# How to change frame to title header (UITableView)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How it is possible to change the x axis to my title header section in swift?

I'm not able to change it using that code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)
{
    let header:UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    header.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12.0)!
    header.textLabel!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left

    header.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.sectionGray()

    //Not working
    header.textLabel!.frame.origin.x = header.textLabel!.frame.origin.x - 60

}
```

Comment: Why you don't use `viewForHeaderInSection` method?

Comment: Instead of changing the frame use transform to translate the label.

Answer (score 1):

```
header.textLabel!.frame = header.textLabel!.frame.offsetBy(dx: -60, dy: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

use view in exith for example

[image]

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *tblCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"gm" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return tblCell;
}
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.tableView;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 100;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
//Not working
    header.textLabel!.frame.origin.x = header.textLabel!.frame.origin.x - 60
```

your cant not change the orign.x or orign.y  but you can change the frame or update the frame

do one thing instead of this opproach

in your storyboard  create one uitableviewCell and design it as you want  and define its class and idntifire as SectionHeader

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    SectionHeaderTableViewCell *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SectionHeader"];

    if (headerView == nil) {
        headerView = (SectionHeaderTableViewCell*)[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SectionHeader"];
    }

    headerView.headerTxt.text=@"THIS WEEK";
        return headerView;
}
```

this is objective C code convert it in swift  this is the most easiest way to play with header

Comment: did you check this @mala

Comment: that is not what i need